# Spivak's Calculus 5-15-vi $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\tan^2(x)+2x}{x+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Evaluate the following in terms of $\alpha = \displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}:$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\tan^2 (x)+2x}{x+x^2}$$

I'm stuck on this one. I've tried using $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ followed by $\cos^2(x)=1 - \sin^2(x)$ to get everything in terms of $x$ and $\sin$. Then I tried in terms of $x$ and $\cos$ (since $\cos$ is on the denominator). Also tried partial fractions. Help.

Comment: can you use L'Hopital? than limit is 2=2*alpha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write
$$\frac{\tan^2 x + 2x}{x + x^2} = \frac{\tan^2 x + 2x}{x(x+1)} = \frac{\dfrac{\sin x}{x} \cdot\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x} + 2}{x+1}$$
and use limit laws to get the limit
$$\frac{\alpha \cdot 0 + 2}{1}$$

Comment: There's an error in the denominator.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. This being said,  it's half a line with asymptotic analysis…

Comment: Of course it is. This is a calculus student asking a question about limits and the toolbox at that point usually involves continuity and limit laws.

Comment: Sure, but find these exercises absurd if for first year university students. As formulated, it is an exercise for high-school.

Comment: How do you know OP isn't in high school?

Comment: Spivak's book is not for high-school.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \cos x=1$, we have $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x}x=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}x=\alpha$, i.e.  $\tan x=\alpha x+o(x)$.

So $\tan^2 x=\alpha^2 x^2+o(x^2)$, and $\tan^2 x+2x=2x+o(x)=x(2+o(1))$.

Then $\frac{ \tan^2 x+2x}{x(1+x)}=\frac{2+o(1)}{1+x}$ and the limit as $x\to 0$ is 2.

Comment: Hot take: the o-notation API for limit laws is just better than the usual pirouettes we teach in calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Given,

$\frac{\tan^2 x+2x}{x+x^2}$ ,

Now taking $"x"$ common from numerator and denominator,

we get,

$$\frac{\tan^2 x+2x}{x+x^2}=\frac{\tan(x)\frac{\tan(x)}{x}+2}{1+x}$$

As we know, $Lim_{x\to0}\frac{tanx}{x}=1$

So,

$$Lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(x)\frac{\tan(x)}{x}+2}{1+x}=\frac{0\cdot1 +2}{1+0}=2$$